# else statement is not working in IF Else statement

Tags: mysql, laravel, if-statement, laravel-5

It is  a bit strange question but I am stucked here. I am just using a query to determine the value of a variable, and I am getting my expected value. But when I pass it to blade file , I get the value if variable. But the condition is not working properly.

**Blade.php**

```
@foreach($rolepermssion as $role)

  @if($rol==1)
    <form method="post" action="{{ url('/system-configurations/roles-permission/permission') }}">

    </form>

  @else
     <form method="post" action="{{ url('/system-configurations/roles-permission/permission') }}">
    </form>    
    @endif
    @endforeach
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function modulePermission(){    
    $rol= RolePermission::where("roles_id", "=", $role_id)->count();

    $rolepermssion=RolePermission::where('roles_id','=',$role_id)->get();
    return view('system-configurations.module-permission',compact('rolepermssion','rol'));
}
```

Comment: is it just for the exemple or your `if` and `else` have the same code? (except for the missing ">" at the end of `</form`. Is it normal also that you have `@foreach($rolepermssion as $role)` and actually testing `@if($rol==1)`? We can't be sure but could you have meant `@if($role==1)`? The "mysql" tag also seems useless here.

Comment: <form> is just formality, main problem is If else. Didn't understand second question. I tagged 'my-sql' beacuse there may be better solution in query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `@if($rolepermssion->count() == 1)`

Comment: Are you sure that you get more than one records?

Comment: Yep. I want to show only one form from many forms depending on the condition.

Comment: And how do you know if you run in the if block, if the two forms are identical?

Comment: Ok let me explain. I am using condition to determine whether id of the form is available or not if it is then form will be used to create a new record with different front-end, else it will update the record. And if form is available it will also show its current values.

Comment: Try to print out all variables with the dd() function. You may find the bug faster using it.

Comment: I have checked that and I have explained above that from controller to balde file I am getting my expected value. But when it comes to condition it is not working according to values

Comment: Please try to change one of the condition blocks to make sure which onw you run into.

Comment: Ok its done. The problem was foreach needed to be closed before starting new form

Answer (score 0):

You start to set the variable `$role` and then you test the variable `$rol`.

Isn't it your problem ?

Comment: Nope. $role is array which contains data from database. $rol contains output for query